# Spec file: File is packed by rpm, but not getting installed in right destination

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Rpm -ql is listing the file but the file is not getting installed in the right location of target machine.

Comment: `rpm -qa` only lists the RPMs you have installed. It doesn't list files.

Comment: yeah, sorry. rpm -ql package_name | grep filename is listing the file. But, the file is not present in the destination location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

1. someone removed that file. In that case simple `dnf reinstall your_package` will fix it
2. or the file is marked as %ghost http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html that is usually for log files. You do not want them to ship, but a package should own them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea why state files are put under %ghost directory and not as a normal file? Would it create any other consequences if a file is unmarked as %ghost? Thanks!!

Comment: If you package state file what would you put in? PID of the process? That it is running or failed? Packager cannot know it. And during the upgrade process rpm would overwrite the real status. You do not want it.

Comment: It contains a value. And a command called save is used to save that value in state file. And load is used to load the value from the state file.

Comment: Here since file is a ghost file, save and load commands are not working. So, is it suggested to unmark the file as %ghost?